# java.sql.SQLException: invalid column index

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I've been trying to select data using preparedStatement and passing these arguments but an Exception happens.

Could anyone help me? Here is my code.

```
Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
    String query = "select * from integrantes where nome like '?' or rm like '?'";
            ArrayList<Integrante> list = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, ('%' + term + '%'));
                preparedStatement.setString(2, ('%' + term + '%'));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ((OraclePreparedStatement) preparedStatement).getOriginalSql());
                ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    list.add(new Integrante(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getString(2), resultSet.getString(3), resultSet.getInt(4)));
                }
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao listar o(s) integrante(s)." + e);
            } catch(NullPointerException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro inesperado.");
            } catch(Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro no código.");
            }

            return list;
```

Comment: `select *` is a poor way to structure a SQL statement rather than listing the columns.  I would guess that your query does not return 4 columns but it's impossible to know.

Comment: select id_integrante, nome, rm id_grupo from integrantes; it works as well when I execute in Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: That is 3 columns not 4 (`id_grupon` is an alias for the `rm` column).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a `PreparedStatement` you must NOT put quotes around placeholders that are going to be substituted with strings.  Your statement

```
"select * from integrantes where nome like '?' or rm like '?'"
```

causes the question marks to be treated as literals, so the statement has ZERO parameters, thus resulting in the exception.  Change it to

```
"select * from integrantes where nome like ? or rm like ?"
```